# VC++ MFC edit box sorting

Tags: datetime, visual-c++, mfc

How do I sort the date and time in decending order in edit box?

Comment: Hi, your question isn't very clear. Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

an edit box contains only one single text (either multiple-lines or single line).

if you want a list of date/time string, use CListBox and it has sort member function. Otherwise you'll need to retrieve the complete string from edit box, load it into an array of lines then sort, and put back the sorted result.